# How to store data pairs in a mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql, database, entity-attribute-value

I have to store a big amount of data pairs. Data pairs are in the form:

> parameter = value

and are related to a container. It's similar to a INI file. For example, I have a container that have these values:

```
p1 = 32
p2 = "hello world"
p3 = -54
```

and another one that have:

```
p1 = 32
p2 = 36
p5 = 42
p6 = "bye"
```

There is an undefined number of parameters per container. The values are numbers or strings of any length (numbers can be converted to strings). Data retrieval is made by parameter name (*"all p1 values"*) or value (*"a 'p6' parameter with the value 'bye'"*). The database will contain milions of pairs. Inserts and reads will be made very often and will be rare to delete or update a record.

My first attempt has been make two tables. First one like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `container` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  OTHER CONTAINER INFO
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

where `id` will be used in another table that contains the pairs:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `data` (
  `container` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `value` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  KEY `container` (`container`),
  KEY `name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Adding the data:

```
INSERT INTO `container` (`id`) VALUES ('1'), ('2');
INSERT INTO  `data` (`container`, `name`, `value`) VALUES 
     ('1',  'p1',  '32'), 
     ('1',  'p2',  'hello world'), 
     ('1',  'p3',  '-54'), 
     ('2',  'p1',  '32'), 
     ('2',  'p2',  '36'), 
     ('2',  'p5',  '42'), 
     ('2',  'p6',  'bye');
```

It works, but it's not very "usable" and fast. For instance, if I need to find all parameters from each container that has a `p1=32` I have to make two SQL queries, first:

```
SELECT id FROM  `container` WHERE id IN (
   SELECT container
   FROM DATA WHERE name =  'p1'
  AND value =  '32')
```

and then for each container `id` get all data:

```
SELECT * FROM  `data` WHERE container = '$id'
```

and then make a post-processing via PHP because it returns a table like this:

```
container   name    value
    1       p1      32
    1       p2      hello world
    1       p3      -54
```

(post-processing is just a couple of calls to array_* functions, but it makes slower the processing).

I've been testing with a database that contains 50000 data pairs and listing all the records using this procedure takes more than 5 seconds. The question is: how to store this kind of data? or how to improve the performance of my implementation?

**NOTE**: The problem is not the first SQL query (0'003 seconds) or the second one (0'002 seconds each one). The problem is to make a SQL query for each result of the first SQL sentence!!

**NOTE 2**: The goal is to have a PHP array that contains each result and for each result an  associative array with pairs key-value. The result for a `print_r`:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [p1] => 32
            [p2] => hello world
            [p3] => -54
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [p1] => 32
            [p2] => 36
            [p5] => 42
            [p6] => bye
        )
)
```

And, of course, the data structure I have shown here is my first attempt, I'm researching, that's not a production, so I can change, no problem at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all the results per container on one line, you probably need to use a pivot table. However, given that you have potentially got a variable number of data.name values, you can't just do this in a single simple query. You'll need to write a proc to dynamically generate the sql.

This link should help you out: http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#78

The resulting SQL should look something like (untested)

```
SELECT 
  c.id, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(if(d.name = 'p1', d.value, NULL)) AS 'p1', 
  GROUP_CONCAT(if(d.name = 'p2', d.value, NULL)) AS 'p2', 
  GROUP_CONCAT(if(d.name = 'p3', d.value, NULL)) AS 'p3', 
  GROUP_CONCAT(if(d.name = 'p4', d.value, NULL)) AS 'p4', 
  GROUP_CONCAT(if(d.name = 'p5', d.value, NULL)) AS 'p5', 
  GROUP_CONCAT(if(d.name = 'p6', d.value, NULL)) AS 'p6', 
FROM container c
JOIN data d ON c.id = d.container
GROUP BY c.id;
```

Giving a result something like:

```
|id    |p1    |p2            |p3    |p4    |p5   |p6  | 
-------------------------------------------------------
|1     |32    |hello world   |-54   |      |     |    |
|2     |32    |36            |      |      |42   |bye |
```

Comment: That's very interesting, but it has a problem: I don't know which pairs are stored, may be exists a p9 or maybe not.

Comment: Yep, I know, thats why you'll need to first write a stored procedure to build the query (see the link). Basically, it should construct a query like in my example, but with a group_concat for all distinct values of data.name (that you're interested in)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need two seperate queries, a join works fine there; the sub-select is not required either. Your two queries become this:

```
SELECT id FROM  `container` c 
JOIN data d ON c.id = d.container
d.name =  'p1'
AND d.value =  '32';
```

Ok I saw your note, do you want all the data in the same row? I wouldn't use this query but are these the results you would want?

```
SELECT id, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS("=", d.name, d.value)) results FROM  `container` c 
JOIN data d ON c.id = d.container
HAVING LOCATE("p1=32", results) > 0;
```

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't work. It just returns the container IDs, the same that my first SQL query

Comment: @Ivan I thought that's what you wanted. It returns the same as your previous query but much faster. This is a much more optimized version of your same select.  What other data do you need?

Comment: That's not the problem. The listing is still taking 5 seconds.  Please, see my note.

Comment: It returns a string ("p1=32,p2=hello world,p3=-54,p1=32,p2=36,p5=42,p6=bye") but I cannot use it because it doesn't have the container ID. I've not tested performance for this. Anyway, that's a good research point I have not explored yet. Thanks.

Comment: It selects 2 columns, first one has the container id second one has all the strings.

Comment: The second query needs to be grouped by container: `GROUP BY d.container`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
   container.id 
FROM 
   `container` 
LEFT JOIN `DATA`
   ON container.ID = DATA.container
WHERE DATA.name =  'p1'
   AND DATA.value =  '32'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just join the data table with itself and you will get all you need in one select:

```
select d2.container, d2.name, d2.value
from data d1
join data d2 using(container)
where d1.name  = 'p1'
  and d1.value = '32';
```

Result:

```
| container | name |       value |
|-----------|------|-------------|
|         1 |   p1 |          32 |
|         1 |   p2 | hello world |
|         1 |   p3 |         -54 |
|         2 |   p1 |          32 |
|         2 |   p2 |          36 |
|         2 |   p5 |          42 |
|         2 |   p6 |         bye |
```

```
$arr = array();
while ($row = $result->fetchAssoc()) {
    $arr[$row['container']][$row['name']] = $row['value'];
}
```

You can also create a valid php-array string in sql:

```
select concat('[', GROUP_CONCAT(d.row), '\n]')
from (
    select concat('\n\t', d2.container, '=>[', GROUP_CONCAT(concat('"', d2.name, '"', '=>', '"', d2.value, '"')), ']') as row
    from data d1
    join data d2 using(container)
    where d1.name  = 'p1'
      and d1.value = '32'
    group by d2.container
) d;
```

Result:

```
[
    1=>["p1"=>"32","p2"=>"hello world","p3"=>"-54"],
    2=>["p1"=>"32","p2"=>"36","p5"=>"42","p6"=>"bye"]
]
```

But why would someone want to do that? ;-)

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a7977/1

**Update** - also try that keys:

```
ALTER TABLE `data` ADD UNIQUE INDEX `container_name` (`container`, `name`);
ALTER TABLE `data` ADD INDEX `name_value` (`name`, `value`(20));
```

You might also want search the web for [entity-attribute-value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model)